# What's the risk of multiple SubmitChanges?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is there a risk with the code below that if two people submit at the same time the wrong s.saleID will be retrieved?

```
        protected void submitSale(int paymentTypeID)
    {
        tadbDataContext tadb = new tadbDataContext();

        ta_sale s = new ta_sale();

        decimal total = decimal.Parse(lblTotal.Value);

        s.paymentTypeID = paymentTypeID;
        s.time = DateTime.Now;
        s.totalSale = total;
        tadb.ta_sales.InsertOnSubmit(s);
        tadb.SubmitChanges();

        char[] drinksSeparator = new char[] {'|'};
        char[] rowSeparator = new char[] { ':' };
        string drinkString = lblSummaryQty.Value.Substring(0, lblSummaryQty.Value.Length - 1);
        string[] arrDrinks = drinkString.Split(drinksSeparator);


        foreach (string row in arrDrinks)
        {
            string[] arrDrink = row.Split(rowSeparator);
            int rowID = Convert.ToInt16(arrDrink[0]);
            int rowQty = Convert.ToInt16(arrDrink[1]);

            ta_saleDetail sd = new ta_saleDetail();
            sd.drinkID = rowID;
            sd.quantity = rowQty;
            sd.saleID = s.saleID;
            tadb.ta_saleDetails.InsertOnSubmit(sd);
        }

       tadb.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

If so, what should I do to make sure it is atomic? (I think it should be OK, but want to double check!)

Answer (score 0):

To be shure that it's ok just write a **test** that call **submitSale** 2 or even more times and make it to submit changes almost at the same time. If test will fail, use **lock** statement, but be carefull, it can cause **deadlocks**. After you change **submitSale** just test it again with high load (a lot of simultaneous calls). And so on until you pass the test.